# Реализация SNMP getbulk

Tags: delphi, indy, snmp

Можно ли реализовать getbulk запрос средствами IdSNMP в Delphi?

```
IdSNMP1.Query.Version:=1;    
IdSNMP1.Query.PDUType := PDUGetNextRequest;
IdSNMP1.Query.MIBAdd(OID,'',2);
while IdSNMP1.SendQuery do
    begin
        if Copy (IdSNMP1.Reply.MIBOID [0], 1, Length (OID)) <> OID then break;
        memo1.Lines.Append('Replies: ' + IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueOID [0] + '  ' + IdSNMP1.Reply.Value[0]);
      IdSNMP1.Query.MIBDelete(0);
      IdSNMP1.Query.MIBAdd(IdSNMP1.Reply.ValueOID [0], '');
      IdSNMP1.Query.PDUType := PDUGetNextRequest
    end
```

В результате этого получаю get-response, а хотелось бы реализовать полноценный getbulk.